# Authorization failure while adding supplier product in spree

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan, spree, spree-auth-devise

Hi I tried to add a product in spree using the supplier login. I have two gems related to spree marketplace installed

```
gem 'spree_drop_ship', github: 'spree-contrib/spree_drop_ship', branch: '3-0-stable'
gem 'spree_marketplace', github: 'firman/spree_marketplace'
```

Also, I updated my ability decorator to provide related authority using

```
if user.has_spree_role? "supplier"
        can [:admin, :manage, :index, :create, :update], Spree::Product do |product|
          product.supplier_ids.include?(user.supplier_id)
        end
end
```

I can see the form to add the product but when I add basic product details and click on create, it give me `Authorization Failure` error
Please suggest what should I do to resolve the issue.

Update: I debugged the app and found there was some migration files missing, when I migrated db, I could see the supplier_id column in spree_products, but when I added new product using the supplier login, same error was being thrown as unauthorized, I checked with database the supplier_id column was `NULL`.

Where should I make changes so that correct supplier id is stored in spree_products

Answer (score 0):

The product is created but not associated to supplier, then raise an authorization failure on edit because that product has no supplier.

You are using the [3-0-stable](https://github.com/spree-contrib/spree_drop_ship/blob/3-0-stable/app/controllers/spree/admin/products_controller_decorator.rb) branch and that branch is missing an important method. Please see the [2-4-stable](https://github.com/spree-contrib/spree_drop_ship/blob/2-4-stable/app/controllers/spree/admin/products_controller_decorator.rb) branch and copy the add_product_to_supplier  method to your Spree::Admin::ProductsControllers.

```
Spree::Admin::ProductsController.class_eval do
  create.after :add_product_to_supplier

  # Newly added products by a Supplier are associated with it.
  def add_product_to_supplier
    if try_spree_current_user && try_spree_current_user.supplier?
      @product.add_supplier!(try_spree_current_user.supplier_id)
    end
  end
end
```